# Pro Asp.Net 2016 nuget Update-Database cmdlet error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Asp.Net Core. While reading Adam Freeman's book on Asp.Net Core (2016)
I have done everything properly prior to my problem, however, I can not create database tables using Update-Database Project manager console command as said in the book. Similar topics did not help me. Here is the error.

```
Invoke must be called on a background thread.
Update-Database : The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Database
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Update-Database:String) [], 
Comman 
dNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: That's what you get for buying a dead tree explaining how to work with technology that's still heavily under development; the book was outdated before it was printed. Just follow the documentation on the asp.net site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ASP.NET Core did you select when created the project?

Did you add both *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* and *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools* packages, did you do that via the Nuget manager or by editing your .csproj and what versions of that packages did you add?

In the book he adds packages by editing *project.json* which is no more supported and is replaced by *PROJECT_NAME.csproj*.

Make sure your dependencies were added and there are no warning signs (In Solution Explorer, expand your project tree. Check if required packages are listed in Nuget section under the "Dependencies" and there is no yellow warning triangle sign on the item).

Comment: Thank you, but I added necessary packages, also I am using VS2017 updated pages by the author. Unfortunately, that was not the issue, and it could not be resolved so I used sample code from the book.